# asMaps with DataTable variable

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I am working on Behaviour Driven Development test - BDD test, for that i am using Cucumber with Gherkin.

In my test function i need to declare a matrix, so in the Given step i declared a table and in the function test i need to give it as a DATATABLE.

To transfer the dataTable elements to int and work with it as a matrix, i used a MAP, but the problem is when i use : `List<Map<String,String>> rows = table.asMaps(String.class, String.class);`
intellij makes **asMaps in red**  and it shows the problem is : **Cannot resolve method 'asMaps' in 'DataTable'**

I didn't find a solution for that in google i will attach the code:

```
package EXO1.com;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import gherkin.ast.DataTable;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DetStep {
    @Given("I have a matrix")
    public void iHaveAMatrix(DataTable table) {
        List<Map<String,String>> rows = table.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
    }

    @When("I call function determinant\\(Matrix matrix)")
    public void iCallFunctionDeterminantMatrixMatrix() {
    }

    @Then("I expect the result {int}")
    public void iExpectTheResult(int arg0) {
    }
}
```

For the feature class is :

```
Feature: Calcul Determinant
  Scenario: determinant d'une matrice
    Given I have a matrix
    |col1|col2|col3|
    |1|2|0|
    |3|1|1|
    |2|0|1|
    When I call function determinant(Matrix matrix)
    Then I expect the result -3
```

Comment: I think you have wrong DataTable import, shouldn't it be cucumber.api.DataTable?

Comment: Hello, thank u so much!! you are right the problem was in importing DataTable i should use : import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable

Comment: You may want to check your dependencies. Sounds like you are mixing different versions.